# Magento 2 Countdown timer with background image

Tags: magento2

I´m using magento 2.1 and I want a countdown timer with a custom background image but I can´t find any FREE countdown timer that actually do what I want.

I want exactly like this: [image]

If someone know how can I do this please comment !
Thank you